# Fetch Api cannot load webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I'm using next js 8 version in relation with react. Also using Apollo and Graphql. But I don't think that problem is in Apollo or Graphql. I have _document.js file in my pages folder. But when using Router.back() I have error about fetch api webpack and cors request. Actual problem is like this in browser console:

> Fetch API cannot load
>   webpack://%5Bname%5D_%5Bchunkhash%5D/./node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js?.
>   URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling an endpoint without the protocol, for example you are doing

```
fetch('localhost:3000/my-endpoint')
```

You need to set put the http or https

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/my-endpoint')
```